# Firestore - Upload image to storage when field in Firestore document is set to true

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to check a boolean value in a document on Firestore (the field name is 'NewImageRequested) and, when this value is set to True (by another application), I have to upload a picture to the storage, and set the value back to False.

So far, I've been doing this:

```py
db_credentials_file = 'local_file.json'

firebase_config = {
    'apiKey': "AIzaSyCi2_82wp1txEv6PbmY7TpPJCA-tlKfXnc",
    'authDomain': "coachmylife-dev.firebaseapp.com",
    'databaseURL': "https://coachmylife-dev.firebaseio.com",
    'projectId': "coachmylife-dev",
    'storageBucket': "coachmylife-dev.appspot.com",
    'messagingSenderId': "317036767832",
    'appId': "1:317036767832:web:6a5a4e61f794bd7db6382d",
    'measurementId': "G-HGE4Q3R0GM",
    'serviceAccount': db_credentials_file
}


firebase_storage = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebase_config)
storage = firebase_storage.storage()
cred = credentials.Certificate(f"{db_credentials_file}")
firebase_data = firebase_admin.initialize_app (cred)
db = firestore.client()
print('Connection initialized')


doc_ref = db.collection(u'CollectionName').document(u'DocumentName')


def main():
    doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)

    doc_watch.unsubscribe()


def on_snapshot (doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            print(f'Document located: {change.document.id}')
        elif change.type.name == 'MODIFIED':
            doc_ref.update({u'NewImageRequested': False})
            print('\tNew image requested, uploading to storage')
            storage.child('images/ipcam/upload_test.png').put('non_local_networks.png')
            print('\tNew image uploaded')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works so far, but I have 2 problems:

1. the upload is triggered everytime any part of the document is changed, not only when 'NewImageRequested' goes from False to True. Is it possible to listen to only this specific field?
2. even better, can I trigger the upload only when 'NewImageRequested' goes from False to True? The way it works now is:

   - 'NewImageRequested' switches from False to True
   - upload image
   - 'NewImageRequested' is set to False
   - another change is detected (True to False)
   - upload image again
   - since 'NewImageRequested' is already False, it's not updated

if I could trigger the upload and the modification of 'NewImageRequested' only when the False-True switch happens, it would save an upload (no big deal, but I wanted to know if that's possible)=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to listen to only this specific field?

Firebase listeners trigger on the entire document, not on field-level changes. You will have to keep the previous snapshot of the document and the new one, and compare them to determine what has changed.

Alternatively you can create a specific document for the "request new image" task, write that to a specific subcollection, and have the client listen for documents in that "task queue".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please point me to some reference on how to do it with Python? I took a look around, but didn't find anything yet.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#python?